# Performing FirebaseFirestore queries from multiple Isolates

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, dart-isolates, flutter-local-notification

The **outline** of what I am trying to achieve is the following:

1. Within the main Flutter app, the user authenticates with FirebaseAuth and afterwards can perform FirebaseFirestore read/writes.
2. The app can launch a notification via [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) plugin. These notifications have actions that should also perform FirebaseFirestore read/writes.

The rough implementation is that my **main() function** does something like this:

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
await Firebase.initializeApp();
// Later on ...
DocumentSnapshot myQuery = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('myCollection').get();
```

The **notification implementation** works somewhat like this:

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse(NotificationResponse notificationResponse) async {
   // This condition seems to be always true
   if (Firebase.apps.isEmpty) {
     await Firebase.initializeApp();
   }
   // This operation finishes successfully
   await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('myCollection').doc('myDoc').set(notificationResponse.payload.toMap());
}
```

While the app on its own does everything as expected and the notification action also carries out successfully, they don't work in combination. **After the notification action is carried out, queries from within the app won't work anymore, requesting me to call Firebase.initializeApp()**

Apart from checking if Firebase was initialized before every query (which is not a viable solution because the app is also subscribed to FirebaseFirestore streams, which also stop working), **is there a solution so that both the app and notification isolates can perform Firestore queries without blocking each other?**

There seems to be surprisingly little information online on this topic, so I really hope you can help me out.

Comment: I think I have similar [Issue](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/10676) with you, Did you fix it?

Comment: Sadly no progress on my side. In the issue you linked, you said you added useAuthEmulator. Can you share a code snippet of that?